# Unable to get JDBC connection in Spring application to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, database-connection

I have following DB Configuration in Spring:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:dburl" />
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="username" value="username" />
            <property name="password" value="passworf" />
            <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
            <property name="initialSize" value="3" />
            <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
        </bean>
```

Additional Configuration to load property values from DB.

```
<bean id="config1" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="tablename1" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="columnname" />
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="columnvalue" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="configFactory1"
        class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="config1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DB Properties Initialization -->
    <bean id="configurationPlaceHolder1"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="configFactory1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="config2" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="tablename2" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="columnname" />
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="columnvalue" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="configFactory2"
        class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
        <constructor-arg ref="config2" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DB Properties Initialization -->
    <bean id="configurationPlaceHolder2"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="configFactory2" />
    </bean>
```

DAO Configuration which gives problem:

```
    <!-- DAO Bean which is causing issue -->
    <bean id="problematicBean" class="com.example.ProblematicDAOImpl" scope="singleton">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
    </bean>
```

When I start application, I am stuck at following line:

```
    17 Feb 2014 15:39:58,981 -  main - DEBUG - 
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:691)  - 
Executing prepared SQL query
            17 Feb 2014 15:39:58,983 -  main - DEBUG - 
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:625)  - 
Executing prepared SQL statement [ SQL STATEMENT ]  


17 Feb 2014 15:39:59,000 -  main - DEBUG -
 org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:110)  
- Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
```

After this line, application hangs and does not respond. It does not throw exception either.

I have done following checks:

- Increased `maxActive` value.
- Increased `initialSize` value.
- Checked `- SQL STATEMENT` being executed in `Query Browser`.

** UPDATE **

I further debugged code, the code hangs @line 642 in `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` for method `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(PreparedStatementCreator, PreparedStatementCallback<T>)`

The line of codes are these:

```
if (this.nativeJdbcExtractor != null) {
                psToUse = this.nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativePreparedStatement(ps);
            }
            T result = action.doInPreparedStatement(psToUse);//Hangs at this line
            handleWarnings(ps);
            return result;
```

Comment: The application hang for first connection or after some time ??

Comment: @NiksTyagi : Its inside a `singleton bean's init` method. Bean is getting initialized at start-up. I will add more configuration for better understanding.

Comment: I you got। It resolved myself. I was using NamedParameterJdbctemplate to call a query with out any parameters.  this hanged while executing prepared statement in spring api. I switched it to JdbcTempalte class. It works fine.

Comment: @LearnMore please create an answer to you question and accept it (or flag it so it gets closed). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you got। It resolved myself. I was using `NamedParameterJdbctemplate` to call a query with out any parameters. this hanged while executing prepared statement in `spring api`. I switched it to `JdbcTempalte` class. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

please check your JRE version, because Microsoft jdbc driver is broken on few JRE-1.6.x version & resulting the thread to hang. Here are more details:- http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7105007

Comment: Could you add more details here, since the link may become invalid some day